# Rails4 with Foundation Icon Fonts 2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foundation-icon-fonts

I want to use "Foundation Icon Fonts 2 on SASS for Rails" gem with Rails4 Project.
https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails

I followed the instruction to install, but I've got following error.

> Showing
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>   where line #18 raised:
>
> File to import not found or unreadable: foundation-icons. Load paths: 
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/app/assets/images
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/app/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/app/assets/stylesheets
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/assets/stylesheets
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/bundle/gems/turbolinks-1.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/bundle/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/bundle/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.3/scss
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/vendor/bundle/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.3/js
>   (in
>   /Users/[Username]/dev/[AppName]/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss.css:16)

Is this gem is not available in Rails4?
If not, how can I use foundation icon fonts2 in Rails4?

Comment: `application.html.erb where line #18` can you show us your `application.html.erb` ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it again, and works fine now. I don't know why it did n't worked last time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think this is because you need to restart your server after installing the gem for the gem engine to work. Seeing as you updated this two days later, I'm guessing you restarted your app in that time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restarting the webserver after installing the gem fixed it for me as mentioned by Jacob Evan Shreve

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails/issues/9

In Rails 4 change this:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'
end
```

to this:

```
gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

The version 2 of this gem doesn't support Rails 4. You should use version 3.
The reason it worked for you is probably that you're not running it in a production.